# Twig extension for sorting Doctrine ArrayCollection

Tags: symfony, twig, arraycollection

I'm trying to write a Twig filter to be able to sort a Doctrine ArrayCollection, but the returned array is not sorted :( Can you please help me to fix this:

```
class SortExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{ 

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('sortby', array($this, 'sortByFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function sortbyname( $a, $b )
    {       
        if ($a->getName() === $b->getName()) {
            return 0;
        }
        if ( $a->getName() < $b->getName() ) {
            return 1;                 
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public function sortByFilter($collection)
    {
        $iterator = $collection->getIterator();
        $iterator->uasort(array($this, 'sortbyname'));

        return $collection;
    }
```

I'm not quite sure if the returned collection in sortByFilter is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are getting the iterator and sorting it.
The method [`getIterator`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php#L278) creates a new `ArrayIterator` which makes a copy of the array.
Then, you are returning the collection, which is not sorted.

[Here is](https://eval.in/43147) a little sample of what happens.

You just have to replace

```
return $collection;
```

By

```
return $iterator;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer and the nice explanation! :)